# Which Flag should I use?

Tags: discussion, review, 10k-tools, spam, flags

As having 10K reputation I was doing flag review. I found bit strange situation for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16370310/996493)

Answer's Screenshot :

> [image]

We can simply see that its spam kind of advertisement post. But this answer was flagged as "Not an answer" by two users.

Flag Queue Screenshot :

> [image]

My question is which flag should I use in this case ?

- My experience says I should use Spam/ It is not welcome in our community Flag
- Flag queue says "Not an Answer"

However using any of the above flag the post is going to delete very soon. But the question which flag is better to use ?

Comment: Thanks for increasing my flag count by 1.

Comment: @hims056, how come that ?

Comment: I just flagged that answer. :)

Comment: @hims056, oh ok, I thought you flagged my question, btw which flag you used ?

Comment: **SPAM SPAM SPAM**

Comment: I think spam flag should be used here. This is clearly spam.

Comment: Yes, I think the same.

Comment: Looks like `not an answer` is flagged by inexperienced SO users.

Comment: Eh, I dunno, @hims056. I've flagged a few thousand of those, and I've been around a while.

Comment: It's straight spam. Just flag it as spam. The other people in the queue got the wrong reason.

Comment: @hims056 Spam is probably more appropriate in this case, but to be fair, it really isn't an answer, either.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi - Yeah but spam's priority should be higher than *not an answer*.

Comment: @hims056 Oh, I agree. I was just saying it's probably not appropriate to dispute the flag, since it's technically valid.

Comment: @hims056, Yes you are correct, **Spam** Post has higher priority.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Undoubtedly flag it as a **SPAM**. Though it is true that the answer is also not an answer. So we should not disagree with a flag not an answer. After all they brought the spam post in our attention.

Answer (score 1):

> However using any of the above flag the post is going to delete very soon. But the question which flag is better to use ?

You can flag it in any of the way ( either as spam or as NAA ), but the better would be flag it as **SPAM**, the reason is

- SPAM flag has higher priority for moderator handling and that's why it will get deleted faster.
- The post comes under SPAM reason.